# Does a local PC's specifications affect the time taken to run a Microsoft Access query?

Tags: database, odbc

TL;DR i have been asked if it's worth upgrading a colleagues PC since Access queries run slow on it.

My question is, when a user runs an Access query on their local machine that connects to a server containing the data warehouse via MySQL ODBC 5.3, does it send a command to the server and simply wait for a response, therefore rendering local PC specifications redundant? Or, does the local machine contribute to processing the query using an amount of it's own system resource, making higher-spec local PC's better to use?

I would imagine the answer is not that simple but i'm curious to see how the queries are actually processed.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any setup like this, yes the query is executed on the remote machine and a result set is returned, but you still have to do access processing on the result set, meaning some CPU, and enough memory to hold it.

So it depends - you would have to see how long it takes to run the query on the server itself before you could really make the call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I suspect the colleague in question is setting up some heinous joins that are causing it to take forever, and that a better spec PC won't exactly do a lot. When you say "access processing", what exactly does this entail?

Comment: If its an ODBC connection, then the result set will need to be rendered into an Access result set, so the data will be read from an ODBC cursor, and written into an Access data set. Or something like that - I dont know access internals. What you can do if you want to see what is being run is look at monitoring on the mySQL machine to see what is being run. The joins *should* be submitted to run on mySQL, but you should try and grab the query and see how long it runs directly on the database server to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Awesome, i'll see if i can jump on the server and monitor how it runs. Thanks for your help!